# Not all features being output

Tags: pyqgis

I have a process in which I receive three sets of data that have constantly varying attribute names. I wrote a processing script to allow me to refactor the attributes and export the refactored layers to both .shp files and Excel workbooks.

When I run the script, all the features for two of the layers are properly written to the outputs. However, one of the layers consistently is truncated in the output. This is the REFETC data in the script.

Can anyone help me understand why all the rows are not being output?

Here is the script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
***************************************************************************
*                                                                         *
*   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
*   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
*   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
*   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
*                                                                         *
***************************************************************************


"""

from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsVectorLayer,
                       QgsMessageLog,
                       QgsProject,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFile,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterField,
                       QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFolderDestination)
from qgis import processing


class RefactorAndExportTablesAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    """
    This is an example algorithm that takes a vector layer and
    creates a new identical one.

    It is meant to be used as an example of how to create your own
    algorithms and explain methods and variables used to do it. An
    algorithm like this will be available in all elements, and there
    is not need for additional work.

    All Processing algorithms should extend the QgsProcessingAlgorithm
    class.
    """

    # Constants used to refer to parameters and outputs. They will be
    # used when calling the algorithm from another algorithm, or when
    # calling from the QGIS console.
    
    INPUTSAVEPATH = 'INPUTSAVEPATH'
    
    SDCS = 'SDCS'
    SDCCOMMID = 'SDCCOMID'
    SDCNAMEEN = 'SDCNAMEEN'
    SDCNAMEFR = 'SDCNAMEFR'
    SDCSATDEP = 'SDCSATDEP'
    SDCLAT = 'SDCLAT'
    SDCLON = 'SDCLON'
    SDCPROVTERR = 'SDCPROVTERR'
    REFSDC = 'REFSDC'
    
    ETCS = 'ETCS'
    ETCCOMMID = 'ETCCOMMID'
    ETCNAMEEN = 'ETCNAMEEN'
    ETCNAMEFR = 'ETCNAMEFR'
    ETCPROVTERR = 'ETCPROVTERR'
    ETCSATDEP = 'ETCSATDEP'
    ETCATDEP = 'ETCSATDEP'
    ETCLAT = 'ETCLAT'
    ETCLON = 'ETCLON'
    REFETC = 'REFETC'
    
    ROADS = 'ROADS'
    ROADID = 'ROADID'
    ROADNAME = 'ROADNAME'
    ROADRANK = 'ROADRANK'
    ROADCLASS = 'ROADCLASS'
    ROADLENGTHKM = 'ROADLENGTHKM'
    ROADLENGTHM = 'ROADLENGTHM'
    REFROADS = 'REFROADS'
    
    

    def tr(self, string):
        """
        Returns a translatable string with the self.tr() function.
        """
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return RefactorAndExportTablesAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        """
        Returns the algorithm name, used for identifying the algorithm. This
        string should be fixed for the algorithm, and must not be localised.
        The name should be unique within each provider. Names should contain
        lowercase alphanumeric characters only and no spaces or other
        formatting characters.
        """
        return 'saveAttributesToExcel'

    def displayName(self):
        """
        Returns the translated algorithm name, which should be used for any
        user-visible display of the algorithm name.
        """
        return self.tr('Package attribute tables to Excel')

    def group(self):
        """
        Returns the name of the group this algorithm belongs to. This string
        should be localised.
        """
        return self.tr('BBF')

    def groupId(self):
        """
        Returns the unique ID of the group this algorithm belongs to. This
        string should be fixed for the algorithm, and must not be localised.
        The group id should be unique within each provider. Group id should
        contain lowercase alphanumeric characters only and no spaces or other
        formatting characters.
        """
        return 'BBF'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        """
        Returns a localised short helper string for the algorithm. This string
        should provide a basic description about what the algorithm does and the
        parameters and outputs associated with it..
        """
        return self.tr("Allow refactoring of fields and export of tables to Excel")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        """
        Here we define the inputs and output of the algorithm, along
        with some other properties.
        """

        # We add the input vector features source. It can have any kind of
        # geometry.
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.SDCS,
                self.tr('Eligible SDCs'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.SDCCOMMID,
                self.tr('Community ID'),
                '',
                self.SDCS
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.SDCNAMEEN,
                self.tr('Name (English)'),
                '',
                self.SDCS
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.SDCNAMEFR,
                self.tr('Name (French)'),
                '',
                self.SDCS
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.SDCPROVTERR,
                self.tr('Province / Territory'),
                '',
                self.SDCS
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.SDCLAT,
                self.tr('Latitude'),
                '',
                self.SDCS
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.SDCLON,
                self.tr('Longitude'),
                '',
                self.SDCS
            )
        )
        #---------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.ETCS,
                self.tr('Eligible Transport Communities'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.ETCCOMMID,
                self.tr('ETC ID'),
                '',
                self.ETCS
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.ETCNAMEEN,
                self.tr('ETC Name (English)'),
                '',
                self.ETCS
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.ETCNAMEFR,
                self.tr('ETC Name (French)'),
                '',
                self.ETCS
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.ETCPROVTERR,
                self.tr('ETC Province'),
                '',
                self.ETCS
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.ETCSATDEP,
                self.tr('ETC Satellite Dependent'),
                '',
                self.ETCS
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.ETCLAT,
                self.tr('ETC Latitude'),
                '',
                self.ETCS
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.ETCLON,
                self.tr('ETC Longitude'),
                '',
                self.ETCS
            )
        )

        #---------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.ROADS,
                self.tr('Eligible Roads'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )
    
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFolderDestination(
                self.INPUTSAVEPATH,
                self.tr('Export tables to Excel Workbook')
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.ROADID,
                self.tr('Road ID'),
                '',
                self.ROADS
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.ROADNAME,
                self.tr('Road Name'),
                '',
                self.ROADS
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.ROADRANK,
                self.tr('Road Rank'),
                '',
                self.ROADS
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.ROADCLASS,
                self.tr('Road Class'),
                '',
                self.ROADS
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.ROADLENGTHKM,
                self.tr('Road Length km'),
                '',
                self.ROADS
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterField(
                self.ROADLENGTHM,
                self.tr('Road Length m'),
                '',
                self.ROADS
            )
        )

        #---------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination (
                'REFSDC',
                'Refactored SDC'
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination (
                'REFETC',
                'Refactored ETC'
            )
        )
        
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination (
                'REFROADS',
                'Refactored roads'
            )
        )
    

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        """
        Here is where the processing itself takes place.
        """

        # Retrieve the feature source and sink. The 'dest_id' variable is used
        # to uniquely identify the feature sink, and must be included in the
        # dictionary returned by the processAlgorithm function.
        
        refsdc = self.parameterAsLayer (
            parameters,
            self.REFSDC,
            context
        )
        
        refetc = self.parameterAsLayer (
            parameters,
            self.REFETC,
            context
        )
        
        refroads = self.parameterAsLayer (
            parameters,
            self.REFROADS,
            context
        )
        #----------------------------------------
        sdcs = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.SDCS,
            context
        )
        
        sdccommid = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.SDCCOMMID,
            context
        )
        
        sdcnameen = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.SDCNAMEEN,
            context
        )
        
        sdcnamefr = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.SDCNAMEFR,
            context
        )
        
        sdclat = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.SDCLAT,
            context
        )
        
        sdclon = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.SDCLON,
            context
        )
        
        sdcprovterr = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.SDCPROVTERR,
            context
        )
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        etcs = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.ETCS,
            context
        )
        
        etccommid = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.ETCCOMMID,
            context
        )
        
        etcnameen = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.ETCNAMEEN,
            context
        )
        
        etcnamefr = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.ETCNAMEFR,
            context
        )
        
        etcprovterr = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.ETCPROVTERR,
            context
        )
        
        etcsatdep = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.ETCSATDEP,
            context
        )
        
        etclat = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.ETCLAT,
            context
        )
        
        etclon = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.ETCLON,
            context
        )
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
     
        roads = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.ROADS,
            context
        ) 
        
        roadid = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.ROADID,
            context
        )
        
        roadname = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.ROADNAME,
            context
        )
        
        roadrank = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.ROADRANK,
            context
        )
        
        roadclass = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.ROADCLASS,
            context
        )
        
        roadlengthkm = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.ROADLENGTHKM,
            context
        )
        
        roadlengthm = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.ROADLENGTHM,
            context
        )
        
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        inputSAVEPATH = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.INPUTSAVEPATH,
            context
        )

        # If source was not found, throw an exception to indicate that the algorithm
        # encountered a fatal error. The exception text can be any string, but in this
        # case we use the pre-built invalidSourceError method to return a standard
        # helper text for when a source cannot be evaluated
        if sdcs is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSourceError(parameters, self.SDCS))
        
        
        # Field types: applicable only to refactor fields
        # 1 Boolean
        # 2 Integer
        # 4 Integer 64
        # 6 Double
        # 10 String
        # 14 Date
        # 16 DateTime
        
        refsdc=processing.run("native:refactorfields", {
            'INPUT':sdcs.sourceName(),
            'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': sdccommid,'length': 60,'name': 'CommID','precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': sdcnameen,'length': 60,'name': 'Name_en','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdcnamefr,'length': 60,'name': 'Name_fr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdcprovterr,'length': 60,'name': 'ProvTerr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': sdclat,'length': 12,'name': 'Latitude','precision': 6,'type': 6},
            {'expression': sdclon,'length': 12,'name': 'Longitude','precision': 6,'type': 6}],
            'OUTPUT':parameters['REFSDC']})
                        
        refetc=processing.run("native:refactorfields", {'INPUT':etcs.sourceName(),
            'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': etccommid,'length': 60,'name': 'CommID','precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': etcnameen,'length': 60,'name': 'Name_en','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcnamefr,'length': 60,'name': 'Name_fr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcsatdep,'length': 15,'name': 'SATDEP', 'precision':0, 'type': 10},
            {'expression': etcprovterr,'length': 60,'name': 'ProvTerr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': etclat,'length': 12,'name': 'Latitude','precision': 6,'type': 6},
            {'expression': etclon,'length': 12,'name': 'Longitude','precision': 6,'type': 6}],
            'OUTPUT':parameters['REFETC']})
            
        refroads=processing.run("native:refactorfields", 
            {'INPUT':roads.sourceName(),'FIELDS_MAPPING':[
            {'expression': roadid,      'length': 60,'name': 'Road_ID',  'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadname,    'length': 60,'name': 'Name', 'precision': 0,'type': 10},
            {'expression': roadrank,    'length': 2, 'name': 'Rank', 'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadclass,   'length': 2, 'name': 'Class',  'precision': 0,'type': 4},
            {'expression': roadlengthkm,'length': 12,'name': 'Length_km','precision': 6,'type': 6},
            {'expression': roadlengthm, 'length': 12,'name': 'Length_m','precision': 6,'type': 6}],
            'OUTPUT':parameters['REFROADS']})
                        
        processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
            {'INPUT': parameters['REFSDC'],
            'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/Eligible_SDCs.xlsx',
            'LAYER_NAME':'Eligible_SDCs',
            'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'overwrite',
            'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
                                                
        processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
            {'INPUT': parameters['REFETC'],
            'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/Eligible_Communities.xlsx',
            'LAYER_NAME':'Eligible_Communities',
            'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'overwrite',
            'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
                                                
        processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
            {'INPUT': parameters['REFROADS'],
            'OUTPUT':inputSAVEPATH+'/Eligible_Roads.xlsx',
            'LAYER_NAME':'Eligible_Roads',
            'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'overwrite',
            'LAYER_OPTIONS':''})
                                                
        return ({self.REFSDC : parameters['REFSDC'], 'REFETC': parameters['REFETC']})
```

---

My apologies but I found the reason for the truncation. One of the fields was too short for the data.  It appears that the behaviour is to skip the row as opposed to truncating the data in the field.

Are there any ways to listen for these issues and handle them or at least be alerted about the skips?

Comment: Shortening the filename might work. `Eligible_Communities.xlsx` -> `Eligible_Com.xlsx`. The only difference I found is the length of the filename. I don't know, but exceeding 255 characters may cause the problem.

Comment: Please revise your question heavily so that only describes what you currently wish to ask.

Comment: Which field do you mention?